# Connection Error: HttpSendRequest ERROR: HRESULT 0x80072efd

Tags: roblox

so today I wanted to play some roblox. so I went on, hit play, and, it just loaded very slowly. I didn't think it was broken, so I continued to wait. after about 30 seconds it came op with the error

> Connection Error: HttpSendRequest failed: HRESULT 0x80072efd

I looked how to fix this, tried every solution there was, and, nothing. I did have an update a couple days ago but it was working after that, so idk. whats going on. I'm very mad because I just got a Roblox gift card and I cant use it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control Panel and Click on Network and Internet then click on Internet options then click on connections (in-between content and programs) then click on LAN settings then make sure the "Use a proxy server for your LAN" checkbox is unchecked. If this is done open roblox again and check if it still isnt working then roblox must be having trouble with the server or they are working on it so have temporarily shut it down.